# "Show Create Table" in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, create-table, describe

I've tried searching for this, but what is the easiest way to execute a "Show CREATE TABLE" statement in Redshift?

I have tried the following:

```
Show Create Table tbl_nme
Show Table tbl_nme
Describe table tbl_nme
```

I've also tried querying **svv_table_info** but I am not seeing any my tables properly displayed in the results. For example, if I created a new table, I would expect it to show up on the system table when I run select * against it, but I am not finding it...

Essentially I am trying to verify if sortkeys are properly implemented on the table. I am connecting to my redshift db via dbvisualizer on a jdbc connection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello Alex,

Thank you for the reference. This could be a potential duplicate as you have mention, but is the method provided in your link 100% accurate? 

On my DBMS tool, (dbvisualizer), when I navigate with the UI to "script > create table" I am not seeing that sort key listed outputted.  I just want to be 100% certain that the query is correct or if my DMBS tool is incorrect.

Comment: probably your tool does not support unique Redshift functionality... the reference above is based on system tables in Redshift and provides a complete statement that includes sort and dist keys

Comment: Thanks you Alex, I have confirmed that the queries are effective showing the sort keys!